# How to configure and build your kernel to define CONFIG_* and generate autoconf.h

Tags: linux, eclipse, makefile, linux-kernel

I am following the guide https://wiki.eclipse.org/HowTo_use_the_CDT_to_navigate_Linux_kernel_source

In step 2 (above link):
Configure and build your kernel to define CONFIG_* and generate autoconf.h. This can be done before or after downloading and installing Eclipse.

Can someone explain what step 2 is referring to? Would it be related to step B below?

This is my current process of compiling the kernel:
a.) make O=/home/name/build/kernel menuconfig
b.) make O=/home/name/build/kernel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1). make O=/home/name/build/kernel menuconfig

```
Generate .config    (configure linux to generate .config)
```

2). make O=/home/name/build/kernel

```
To compile kernel code
```